# dynamically check if function doesn't exist in object class

Tags: javascript, object

I'm trying to create a jQuery style object class.

```
function obj(id){
    if (this.__proto__.constructor !== obj) {
        return new obj(id);
    }
    this.element = document.getElementById(id);

    this.remove = function(){
        this.element.parentNode.removeChild(this.element);
    }
    this.offset = function(){
        return this.element.getBoundingClientRect();
    }
}
obj(id).offset() // defined
obj(id).removeChild() //undefined
obj(id).appendChild() // undefined
obj(id).remove() // undefined
```

I got a problem. jQuery object can also use as a Javascript DOM object like `$('#someid').innerHTML`, but my object. I'm thinking about a solution that dynamically checks if a method does not exist in this object class, then return a DOM object `return this.element`.

How could I do this? Or any better ideas?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by *"jQuery style object class"*, but a jQuery object can't be used as a DOM object like `$("#someid").innerHTML`.

Comment: You're mistaken: jQuery *cannot* chain DOM methods to jQuery objects (`$('#someid').innerHTML` is a syntax error).

Comment: *"jQuery object can also use as a Javascript DOM object like `$('#someid').innerHTML`"* No, it can't. `innerHTML` there would also be `undefined`. jQuery objects are wrappers around sets of elements. You could do `$('#someid')[0].innerHTML` (note the accessor).

Comment: The only way AFAIK to accomplish what you describe would be to use `Proxy`, which isn't available in most browsers yet since it's part of the next ECMAScript standard, which isn't finalized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> jQuery object can also use as a Javascript DOM object like `$('#someid').innerHTML`

No, it can't. `innerHTML` there would also be `undefined`. jQuery objects are wrappers around sets of elements. You could do `$('#someid')[0].innerHTML` (note the accessor, `[0]`).

> ...checks if a method does not exist in this object class...

If you want to test for the existence of a function, you can use `typeof`:

```
if (typeof obj.method === "function")
```

Note that for certain host-provided functions on some older browsers, you may get `"object"` instead of `"function"`, so you have to allow for that.

But you'd have to do that where you're *using* the function.

> I'm thinking about a solution that dynamically checks if a method does not exist in this object class, then return a DOM object return this.element.

This is a bad idea. Instead, provide a means of accessing the underlying element (the way jQuery does). It will be possible with [ES6's proxies](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3adirect_proxies), but those aren't available widely yet.